# Problemas caché virtuemart

Tags: cache

Buenas, tengo recién instalado el virtuemart, en joomla configuración global tengo deshabilitada la caché, pero resulta que cuando hago cambios en virtuemart se me guardan varios archivos de virtuemart en la caché, y los tengo que borrar manualmente, ¿alguien podría decirme que hago para borrarlos automáticamente?

Answer (score 0):

Pero centrándonos en Joomla! y el maravilloso mundo de las extensiones que lo rodean, hablaremos de CacheCleaner, una extensión que lleva un tiempo evolucionando la ayuda en la tarea de la limpieza de la cache en Joomla sin perder el foco de lo que estamos haciendo.

También podemos evitar el cacheo de nuestros contenidos utilizando "directivas de cache" en los "metas" de nuestras cabeceras HTTP:

```
< meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, private" > 
< meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="nocache" >
```